# edit and delete in same form using laravel

Tags: php, rest, laravel

I have a laravel form built like this:

```
{{Form::model($show, ['method' => 'PUT', 'route' => ['shows.update',$show->id],'files' => 'true']);}}
@include('shows.partials.form')
{{Form::close()}}
```

which I use for editing my forms. However I now want to add a delete button to that form to be able to delete the current item being edited. How would I achieve this? Is there a clean way of doing this?

Comment: You can add a delete button within the form and listen for click on that button (and prevent default) and submit it to your delete route. Perhaps by modifying the action attribute of the form to your delete route and triggering submit. Hopefully that made sense to you? Or submit it using ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible to nest forms due to html5 specifications, therefore laravel dont allow nested Forms. An easy way to handle that is to define your forms one after another and submit the forms with an onclick event. That way u dont need to write bloated jquery scripts.

For example:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' =>URL::Route("routename", $id), 'method' => 'DELETE', 'name' => 'delete')) }}
   some visual stuff
{{ Form::close() }}
.
.
.
{{ Form::open(array('url' =>URL::Route("routename2"), 'method' => 'put', 'name' => 'save', 'files' =>true)) }}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onCLick="document.forms.delete.submit()">
       <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete
</button>
some another visual stuff
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this:

```
<button type="button" id="delete_submit">Delete</button>
```

Js/jQuery:

```
$('#delete_submit').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // $.ajax({})
    // or modify attribute of the form
    // then #('#your_form').trigger('submit');
});
```